# A text input box on a table

Tags: php, html

I have this code that selects data from a database. I want to introduce a last column called "Receipt" however, this will be a text area column where a user can key in a receipt number aligned to every record and submit to save. My challenge is how do I include the form so that the text box will align with every record fetched from the database. Any one? Thanks
This way [How to Make input text field inside table cell in JQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075346/how-to-make-input-text-field-inside-table-cell-in-jquery-datatables/38075715?noredirect=1#comment63588909_38075715)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th><th>TransactionID</th><th>Mobile Number</th><th>Time Paid</th><th>Account</th></tr>";

 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["amount"]. "</td><td>" . $row["trans_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["msisdn"]. "</td><td>" . $row["time_paid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["status"]. "</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: would suggest to add a `<td><input/></td>` to your code and it'll allign automatically

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["amount"]. "</td><td>" . $row["trans_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["msisdn"]. "</td><td>" . $row["time_paid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["status"]. "</td><td>" . $row["account"]. "</td><td> 
 ?> <form action="">
          <input type="text" name="num" value="jj">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>";
  </form>`  Tried this but not working @Ctc

Comment: why is this here `?>`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Tried this but not yet @Ctc ...     
     `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["amount"]. "</td><td>" . $row["trans_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["msisdn"]. "</td><td>" . $row["time_paid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["status"]. "</td><td>" . $row["account"]. "</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="New Principal Name" class="txt8" name="add"></td></tr>";
     }`

Answer (score 1):

You have no format for the table as of what is posted. Add this at the top of your PHP file.

```
echo "<h2 class=\"text-left\"My Table</h2><hr/>
                <table class=\"table\">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Column 1</th>
                      <th>Column 2</th>
                      <th>Column 3</th>
                      <th>Column 4</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>";
```

Afterwards, add your while statement, and then close it with

```
echo "</tbody>
        </table>"
```

Comment: Here is my code @Ctc `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th><th>TransactionID</th><th>Mobile Number</th><th>Time Paid</th><th>Account</th><th>Receipt Number</th></tr>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["amount"]. "</td><td>" . $row["trans_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["msisdn"]. "</td><td>" . $row["time_paid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["status"]. "</td><td>" . $row["account"]. "</td><td><input type="text" name="add"></td></tr>";} echo "</table>";`

Comment: what is your result when ran?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: as in, how does your html look like in the final result?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' .....the text on the input

Comment: Well the table is okay and displaying well. The challenge is having to place an input and submit text area. @Ctc